# How To Add Woocommerce Product Categories To Menu Dynamically?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, menuitem

Is it possible to add a Woocommerce product category to the menu dynamically?
How can I do this? I am trying to add woocommerce product category to the menu dynamically. I am expecting a good solution to this problem. I am Unable to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this using the available Wordpress hooks. One such hook you can use is the `wp_nav_menu` filter ([see documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu/)). This hook allows you to directly modify the output of the nav menu HTML. Be careful, as this will affect all menus unless you set a condition based on the args from the 2nd argument in the filter.

An example implementation

```php
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'example_func',10,2);

function example_func(string $nav_menu, $args): string
{
    // Get categories
    $categories = get_categories(['taxonomy' => 'product_cat']);

    //create new unordered list and append to end of navigation.
    $nav_menu .= '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $cat) {
       $nav_menu .= '<li>' . $cat->name . '</li>'
   }
   $nav_menu .= '</ul>';

return $nav_menu;
```

If you are wanting to place the products in a specific place, you may be better off looking at creating a custom Nav Walker [see docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) or changing your filter to a more precise spot.